# Is this a possible xss vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

On my website, when I go to console under **dev tools**, I am able to run following commands:

```
template = document.createElement("template")
template.innerHTML = "<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>"
div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML = template.innerHTML`
```

When I run this, a popup shows:

'1'. Is this a valid vulnerablity?

If it is, then how can we expand it to do more critical stuff. And what is the possible solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think it would be? Do you allow random scripts to be run in your page? What meaningful thing do you think this let's you do? How would you exfiltrate or otherwise harm a user? Your question is too broad.

Comment: You can also open a command prompt and remove files from your computer. A vulnerability involves crossing security boundaries. Whatever you inflict to yourself is not an attack.

Answer (score 1):

Not it is not, but you could use protection like [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) and read up on how it works [XSS OWASP Foundation](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). Also you can check vulnerabilities with [Google CSP Evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your code, how you handle input and what process is taken before persistence, it's hard to really say yes or no.

I'd recommend checking out https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/, not specifically for XSS, in general a good website for keeping on-top of common vulnerabilities.

The reason I lean toward no: making changes client side is pretty novel, for example open your dev tools, delete all the source code and notice the page is now blank. You're a pro hacker until you hit refresh.

The problem would be if the change isn't client-side, I.E the injected script is permanently in your app, a refresh wouldn't fix this and in that case you've introduced a XSS vulnerability.

Finally, you can run all sorts of client-side commands in the console, although in reality, most times it'll have no permanent effect, try `alert()`, or even try referencing some of the methods within your code.

EDIT: props for asking the question, a lot of people would simply overlook it and hope for the best.